# Differences between downsampling and upsampling

Tags: fourier

Explain why the amplitude of the Fourier transform of a sampled signal changes when downsampling, but not when upsampling.

Comment: Can you add more context? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Do you know what downsampling and upsampling are?  If not, please do some research.  If yes, then consider what happens to the bandwidth of the input signal as it is either upsampled or downsampled.  Then consider what impact that has on its Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

That is because downsampling aliases the spectrum, while upsampling duplicates it. As an example, consider a sampled, single-tone signal:
[image: Sampled Single-Tone]

The DFT of this signal has a single tone, as expected.
[image: Single-tone Spectrum]

If we downsample by throwing away every other sample, we would alias any high frequency content but since there isn't any we still have a single tone.
[image: Downsampled Waveform]
[image: Downsampled Spectrum]

When we upsample, we add samples in-between each existing sample. We have to add these samples with a value of '0' since the upsampling processes doesn't know the original signal.
[image: Upsampled Waveform]
The upsampled spectrum is duplicated and now has two tones. The magnitude of each tone is reduced by 1/2 but the total power of the DFT is the same.
[image: Upsampled Spectrum]

If we re-downsample this signal by throwing away every other sample (the '0's we added) then the high-frequency tone would alias to a lower frequency and the magnitude of the lower frequency tone would increase. For more detailed analysis, check out [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem).

How you determine the best value of the '0' valued samples added during upsampling is the job of the interpolation filter. A good video discussing this for digital audio is on [xiph.org](https://xiph.org/video/vid2.shtml).

Comment: thanks!! is there a way to prove it using Parseval's Theorem?